# Snowflake - query to find roles that haven't been used recently

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to delete roles in Snowflake that haven't been used recently.

Is there a way to query the last date a role was used to execute a query? `query_history` seems promising, but according to the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html#), it only allows `query_history_by_user`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get that from the SNOWFLAKE database. Just keep in mind that the data in the Snowflake database is up to 3 hours delayed, but most views are about 15-20 minutes or so delayed:

```
-- This shows all roles used in the last 30 days
select  ROLE_NAME 
from    SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY
where   END_TIME >= dateadd(day, -30, current_timestamp)
group by 1
;

-- This shows all roles:
select NAME as ROLE_NAME from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.ROLES where DELETED_ON is null
;

-- Combine the two and join to get unused roles in the last 30 days:
with USED_ROLES as
(
select  ROLE_NAME 
from    SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY
where   END_TIME >= dateadd(day, -30, current_timestamp)
group by 1
), ROLES as
(
select NAME as ROLE_NAME from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.ROLES where DELETED_ON is null
)
select ROLE_NAME from ROLES where ROLE_NAME not in (select ROLE_NAME from USED_ROLES)
```

Comment: Isn't that approach potentially produce a lot of "false positives"? I.e., with [two-level hierarchy](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-considerations.html#label-aligning-object-access-with-business-functions) (functional and access roles) the access roles may be returned as unused.

Comment: I think it's worth considering as a caveat. The first query shows the `current_role()` a user had set on their session when running the query. When using this to find unused roles, the thought is that people will not assume that inherited roles are unused. The user will have to review this information and decide why a role hasn't been used. For example in my lab I didn't use the SECURITYADMIN role in the previous 30 days but I know not to drop it. It did find some other roles that I could drop though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that returns the role name and the last date that it was used. Note that the `query_history` view [only has data for the last 365 days](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html), so you cannot return a date for roles that haven't been used in > 1 year:

```sql
with RECENTLY_USED as (
    select ROLE_NAME, max(END_TIME) as last_query_date  
    from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY
    where END_TIME >= dateadd(day, -30, current_timestamp)
    group by 1
), 

LAST_YEAR as (
    select ROLE_NAME, max(END_TIME) as last_query_date  
    from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY
    where END_TIME >= dateadd(year, -1, current_timestamp)
    group by 1
)

select ROLE_NAME, LAST_QUERY_DATE from LAST_YEAR  
minus 
select ROLE_NAME, LAST_QUERY_DATE from RECENTLY_USED
order by LAST_QUERY_DATE;
```

Output:

| ROLE_NAME | LAST_QUERY_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| My_old_role | 2022-04-21T11:44:38.384-05:00 |
| My_other_old_role | 2022-06-07T15:14:45.245-05:00 |

Answer (score 0):

If your query uses permissions from multiple roles, I believe it only logs primary role used. If inherited/nested roles or 'secondary roles all' are used, they do not appear in query_history.